# Wordpress wp_list_pages() with permalinks

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, permalinks

I'm using wp_dropdown_pages() in Wordpress. It's working fine, displaying a nice refined dropdown list of pages. My issue is that the value of each select holds the page ID, not it's permalink - do any of you guys know how I can replace this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find this file: wp-includes/post-template.php

Find this line inside function `start_el()`:

```
$output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"$page->ID\"";
```

(It should be on line 1415). And replace it with this:

```
$output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"".get_permalink($page->ID)."\"";
```

I'm not sure if it's the proper way, but it will get the job done!

Comment: Sasha, you rock! You're the only person who was able to provide something concrete - thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Changing wp-core files is not recommended, after update your WP this file will be rewrite

Comment: Yeah, good point - it'll do as a hackfix for now. If anybody knows of any update-friendly solutions please do post them here :)

Comment: Copy this Fuction in u theme on folder /modules/my-changes-in-core.php rename, change it, and use new, own function, but don't forgot include file with new function :)

Comment: I've had an issue with this fix - for some reason when saving pages their page parent is dropping its value. Removing this fix solved the issue - any ideas how to tweak it to work alongside this functionality?